# Is there a regex to mask middle areas of a dynamic alphanumeric string?

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I am trying to mask some confidential information which can be any alphanumeric string for ex .

*Example 1*

Before masking - PMGKJGFWB125
After masking - PMG******125

*Example 2*

Before masking - 19000
After masking - 1**00

I was trying something like this in C#

Regex.Replace(s, @"\d(?!\d{0,3}$)", "*")

The length of string may vary so we cannot add hardcoded offsets .

Can I get some help on this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any kind of pattern in your examples. Seems like you just chose random blocks to * out. Can you explain better what the regex has to match on?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Also, are you using C# (as the code implies) or JavaScript?  They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like, roughly roughly, you want to divide your string up into quarters and then star out the middle two quarters

Don't get too technical..

```
var str = "PMGKJGFWB125".ToCharArray();

for(int x = str.Length/4; x < str.Length*3/4; x++)
  str[x] = '*';

return new string(str);
```

You can adjust the 4 for different length strings e.g. if your string is 6 or less maybe do 3 instead of 4.. etc

If you want it as LINQ, for a "WTH is that?!" laugh:

```
(int f, int t) = (str.Length/4, str.Length*3/4);
return string.Concat(str.Select((c,i)=>f<i&&i<t?'*':c)));
```